# How to install endeca?

Tags: search, download, installation, endeca

I wan't to learn Endeca Search. After searching a lot I have not found any link to download and install Endeca. I am using windows XP Service Pack 2(32 bit). Where should I download it? How should I install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Endeca isn't free, you can still download it from Oracle's software delivery cloud: https://edelivery.oracle.com.  You'll not be able to use it in a production environment without purchasing a license from Oracle.

@PaulLemke  had good links to the contacts and docs.  If you want to ask questions, you can either use My Oracle Support (for paid customers) or the free forums on OTN: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/category.jspa?categoryID=514.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below links for quick and easy install of Endeca

Install Endeca on Mac
http://www.gingercart.com/Home/developer-handy/installing-endeca-on-mac-osx

Install Endeca on Linux
http://www.gingercart.com/Home/developer-handy/install-endeca-commerce-guided-search-on-linux

Install Endeca on Windows
http://www.gingercart.com/Home/developer-handy/installing-endeca-commerce-search-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Endeca is not a free product and therefore is not publicly available for download. To get an evaluation copy of the software you will have to contact Endeca's new ownere: Oracle.

On the Endeca [homepage](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/commerce/endeca/Overview/index.html) there is a "Global Contacts" on the right side which will help you get in contact with someone that can help you get a copy of the install.

Here is the [documentation index.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/endeca/documentation/documentation-1544963.html) Here is the latest [install guide.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_install/toc.htm) The installation is pretty straight forward depending on the OS.

Comment: Also the current versions of Endeca requires a 64 bit OS

Comment: Yea, that's listed in the install requirements. Good mention.

Comment: @Paul Lemke Thanks a lot for great answer.It is sad that it is not free.

Comment: @Wiszh thanks a lot for configuration information.It require very high configuration.

Comment: @JagdevSingh If you want a free search engine check out Solr: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/